# How to round down to nearest X number - pseudocode for VBScript

Tags: javascript, vbscript, rounding

I'm trying to round down a number to the nearest say 15, 20, 30. ie

726 to the nearest 30 is 700

714 to the nearest 15 is 700
etc

VBScript code would be very helpful but pseudocode would also be a huge help!

**EDIT:** Sorry, I forgot to say, that 726 is really a time expressed as an int, ie 07:26. So this should be 07:00, not 690

**EDIT Again:** I'm just extracting the minute and using the code people have answered with. Hopefully this will help someone else too. Thanks!

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean 726 (rounded down) to the nearest 30 is 720 and 714 (rounded down) to the nearest 15 is 705.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that its really times, please see the question. Really sorry, my mistake

Comment: can you please further clarify how time like 5:45pm would appear in your int representation and if the last 2 digits are ever over 59...

Comment: Thanks Oded, all sorted with your original code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pseudo code:

```
diff = num mod nearest
return num - diff
```

So 726 mod 30 = 6

726 - 6 = 720

vbscript:

```
Function GetNearest(num, nearest)
    Dim diff = num mod nearest
    GetNearest = num - diff
End Function
```

Comment: i thought that modulo is a remainder, that is 726 mod 30 = 6 :)

Comment: Thanks Oded, your answer was perfect, just my question wasnt.

Comment: i think there was a typo in your original answer that is why i put my comment.

Comment: Actually, in VBScript, I've just got the minute out and used this function, works perfectly, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You listed a bunch of languages in your tags.  I'm going with C#, but a more generic algorithm:

```
int n = 726;
int q = 30;
int r = Math.Floor(n / q) * q;
```

Comment: Math.Floor(n / q) is the same as n / q if all the variables are integers.

Comment: @akonsu: True, but not necessarily in all languages.  I thought I'd make the flooring more explicit for use with scripting languages where the types can get muddled.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate this is just the same as using MOD

Answer (score 1):

another way to do it is just to use integer division: 726 / 30 * 30 = 720